# How can I set my DropDelegate and DragDelegate for my TableView nested in my CollectionView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have been working at this for a while. I am not sure if it is the best approach but I have created a collectionView with a custom UICollectionViewCell to include a tableView within. So far everything is working fine, but now I am trying to add drag interaction but can't seem to get that working.

I am trying to achieve having a interactive tableView within each CollectionViewCell if that is possible.

I did try to set my delegates here but it gave me:
`Cannot assign value of type 'CommodityCropCardCell' to type 'UITableViewDropDelegate?'`
Here is my UICollectionViewCell Code (CommodityCropCardCell):

```
class CommodityCropCardCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    static var identifier : String = "CommodityCropCardCell"
    weak var cropCardTableView : UITableView!
    var cropItems : [cropCardInputs]!

    override init(frame:CGRect){
        super.init(frame:frame)
        let cropCards = UITableView()
        let cropItems : [cropCardInputs] = []
        self.contentView.addSubview(cropCards)


        self.cropCardTableView = cropCards
        self.cropItems = cropItems
        cropCards.dataSource = self
        cropCards.delegate = self


//        cropCards.dragInteractionEnabled = true
//        cropCards.dragDelegate = self
//        cropCards.dropDelegate = self


        cropCards.register(cropCardsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cropCardsCell")
        cropCards.reloadData()
        cropCards.dragInteractionEnabled = true

        casesLabel.isHidden = true
        self.reset()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init code error")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.reset()
    }
    func reset(){

        print("resetting")
    }
}
```

Here is my CropCardsViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource:

```
extension CropCardsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionCropCard.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CommodityCropCardCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CommodityCropCardCell
    let data = self.data[indexPath.item]
    cell.titleLabel.text = data.title
    cell.casesLabel.text = "\(data.cases)"
    cell.cropItems = data.cards
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Until your cell adopts the protocol `UITableViewDropDelegate` you will get that error. Adopt the protocol to fix the error.